# Bulk insertion from tibco activespace to Cassandra fails after 3k-4k

Tags: java, cassandra, threadpool, batch-processing, tibco

I am able to do insert operation of 50k records into tibco active spaces by using a thread pool of 25 threads where the pool is executed by ExecutorService.

but, How can we perform bulk database insertions in Cassandra?

I tried in following way:

- Created a subclass to tibco [Persister](https://docs.tibco.com/pub/activespaces/2.1.4/doc/html/tib_activespaces_java_ref/api/javadoc/com/tibco/as/space/persistence/Persister.html), using it when a write operation happens at activespace [Persister#onWrite()](https://docs.tibco.com/pub/activespaces/2.1.4/doc/html/tib_activespaces_java_ref/api/javadoc/com/tibco/as/space/persistence/Persister.html#onWrite(com.tibco.as.space.persistence.WriteAction)) is executed.
- Inside onWrite() a insert statement is executed to put the data into Cassandra by session.execute().

Like:

```
BoundStatement bind = statement.bind(i, "John", "Tester");
session.execute(bind);
```

which fails after 3k to 4k record insertions with the following error.

> com.tibco.as.space.ASException SYS_ERROR persister_cnt=0,
>   min_persister_cnt=1

The above exception not raised, when the heap size is set to 4gb. Is this the correct way to to do it?

Answer (score 0):

The typical design pattern to insert tones of data to Apache Cassandra is to asynchronously execute statements (*Session#executeAsync(...)*), collect future objects in list, and finally wait for their completion (*ResultSetFuture#getUninterruptibly(...)*). You will need two loops to achieve this. Example: https://lostechies.com/ryansvihla/2014/09/22/cassandra-query-patterns-not-using-the-in-query-for-multiple-partitions/.